# How to logout a user from the database with flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a web application made with python/flask, and I use flask-login to authenticate users. In the user interface a user can logout. But the user can also be logged out by the database (when a session expires, or when the user expires).

My user loader looks like this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    user = SessionUser.find_by_session_id(id) #hits the database
    if user is None:
        flash('You have been automatically logged out')
        #flask_login.logout_user() #RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
        session['user_id'] = None
    return user
```

When the database can't find the `id`, I want the user to be logged out. Reasons are: there is no need to hit the `SessionUser.find_by_session_id`-call more than once if an `id` can't be found. Also, I want show a message the user has been logged out (and I only want to show this once). Finally, when a user is logged out of the database, I want to user the unauthenticated templates.

If I don't have the `if user is None:` code, the user loader it hit with every request. There are two problems with this:

1. I can't flash the message "You have been automatically logged out" (because it will keep on showing)
2. There is an unnecessary database hit.

I fixed this by clearing the session-variable `user_id`, but this is an unwanted solution, since it users the internals of `flask_login`, not an API.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

Like @Sraw said, don't manually logout users from `user_loader`. That should only return the user for given id or `None`:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    return SessionUser.find_by_session_id(user_id)  # hits the database
```

The above answers your quesion:

> When the database can't find the id, I want the user to be logged out.

Now, to answer your second question:

> I want show a message the user has been logged out (and I only want to
>   show this once)

Here's the ways a user can be logged out:

1. `user_id` is not in your database (the user was deleted)
2. `user_id` is not in the user's browser cookie session (has not logged in yet, or cleared their cookies)
3. You called `flask_login.logout_user`, which removes `user_id` from `session`

Here's a working mini-app that flashes a message when the user is logged out:

```
from flask import current_app as app, flash, redirect, render_template, session
from flask_login import login_manager, login_required, logout_user


@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    return SessionUser.find_by_session_id(user_id)


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    if session.get('was_once_logged_in'):
        # prevent flashing automatically logged out message
        del session['was_once_logged_in']
    flash('You have successfully logged yourself out.')
    return redirect('/login')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if app.current_user.is_authenticated:  # already logged in
        return redirect('/home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = SessionUser.find_by_session_id(request.data['user_id'])
        if user:
            login_user(user)
            session['was_once_logged_in'] = True
            return redirect('/home')
        flash('That user was not found in the database.')
    if session.get('was_once_logged_in'):
        flash('You have been automatically logged out.')
        del session['was_once_logged_in']
    return render_template('/login.html')


@app.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return 'You are logged in as {0}.'.format(app.current_user.id)
```

Contents of `login.html`:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<form method="post">
  User ID: <input type="text" name="user_id" /><br />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This solution might work, because when a session expires, you always go to the login page. I also realize I need to think a bit deeper about the issue. When the database returns None, it can be because either the db-session expired, or the db-useraccount expired. Also, when you use `flask.session.permanent=True`, there is an extra case why the user needs to login. Also: I still don't like the situation when the `user_loader` returns `None`, the session-variables keep existing. I think Flask-Login needs to support some kind of implicit-logoff which can be called from the user loader.

Comment: I don't think introducing an extra session-variable is an good idea. Why is it so important not to delete the 'user_id' from the session?

Comment: @doekman the Flask Session is how you're flashing messages to the user, and is not a bad thing. Don't store user data in cookies, then you don't have to worry about clearing cookies/Session on logout. If you really must delete the user's Session cookie then just do that when the line after calling `logout_user()`.

Comment: We are clearly not seeing each others point. I think I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to manually logout user if his session has expired in database.

Check [this](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works).

As you can see, if `user_loader` return `None`, that means this user is invalid, so it will be removed from current session which is the same as `logout`. So what you need to do is just `return SessionUser.find_by_session_id(id)`.

## Update

The following snippet should work as you expect. If not, there may be something else wrong.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    # print(id)  # try printing current user's id to check.
    user = SessionUser.find_by_session_id(id) #hits the database
    if user is None:
        flash('You have been automatically logged out')
    return user
```

Comment: if I understand your answer correctly, when you call `@login_manager.user_loader`, it will automatically search for a user_id, and if not found, will clear its `session` variable ?

Comment: It seems you are misunderstanding something... or not? You use `@login_manager.user_loader` to decorate a function. This function accepts `id` as parameter and return `User` object. And if returned object is `None`, `flask-login` will treat this user as invalid and remove this user from `session`. To be more explicit, `flask-login` get user's id from cookie and use this id to get corresponding `User` object. The second progress is done by `login_manager.user_loader`.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your edition. You needn't to manually manage session but just return `None` and let `flask-login` to automatically logout current user. Could you first try this solution? You can test if it is `None` by `if object is None`, this is a more pythonic way, do not use `if object == None`.

Comment: Thanks for the `is None` remark. Still learning python. But my two issues persist. I want to flash a message to the user when he/she is automatically logged out once. Also, I don't understand why `user_loader` is keeps being called with the (expired) session_id,  while the user is logged out. If `user_loader` returns None for a given id, what is the reason it keeps calling `user_loader` with this id. I don't want to call the database another time, and I also don't think a caching solution on the database layer is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem however, is it will flash "You have been automatically logged out" with every request...

Comment: @doekman `user_loader` must be called on every browser request made to your server, because every request is treated independently. That's how HTTP and REST work: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/restful-services-part-i-http-in-a-nutshell-aab3bfedd131